# change boolean field to True after Payment?

Tags: python, django, django-views, stripe-payments

I use stripe Api Payment method and I have a boolean filed in my database called `ordered` set to False

I just want it to be True after payment

Here is my views.py:

```
class OrderSummary(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        order = Order.objects.get(user=self.request.user) #this is to bring the order
        delivered = order.ordered
        YOUR_DOMAIN = "http://127.0.0.1:8000"
        checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
         payment_method_types=['card'],
             metadata={
                "order_id":order.id,
                "order":order,
                "delivered":delivered
            },
            mode='payment',
            success_url=YOUR_DOMAIN + "/",
            cancel_url=YOUR_DOMAIN + "/",
        )
        
        return JsonResponse({'id': checkout_session.id})
```

And here is after payment webhook views:

```
@csrf_exempt 
def stripe_webhook(request):
    payload = request.body
    sig_header = request.META['HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE']
    event = None
    try:
        event = stripe.Webhook.construct_event(
        payload, sig_header, endpoint_secret
        )
       

    except ValueError as e:
        # Invalid payload
        return HttpResponse(status=400)
    except stripe.error.SignatureVerificationError as e:
        # Invalid signature
        return HttpResponse(status=400)
    if event['type'] == 'checkout.session.completed': #this is to bring the order
        session = event['data']['object']
        customer_email = session["customer_details"]["email"]
        orders =session["metadata"]["delivered"]
        orders=True
        orders.save()
        print(session)
    # Passed signature verification

    return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

but I got this error

```
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'save'
```

Comment: You probably need some error handling, but on top of that you are assigning "orders" as a string value and a bool value on top of it. That won't work.  You may want to change orders to something else for the true/false value

Comment: something else  LIKE What !!

Comment: you won't get much help by yelling at people.  good luck

Comment: sorry i didnot mean to yelling i just wanted Capitalize it , sorry man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling save on a variable which is not your model object.

Try:

```
Order= OrderSummary.Objects.get(id=id)
Order.Ordered=True
Order.save()
```

Comment: select this as the answer so your question can help others.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you can not .save() a variable (orders here) , you must .save() the model, so you must retrieve the Order object and set its ordered to True and then .save() the Order object.